# What is the best way to create a configuration file in bash?

Tags: bash

I use bash to configure many of my build tools.

I want to use variables to set certain things so that the build tools can be used in many environments.

Currently I do

```
exports var=val
```

and then I do

```
$var
```

when I need to use it.

Is this the best way to go about it, as I know there are many ways to do things in bash.

```
**Example**

#!/bin/bash

path_bash="$HOME/root/config/bash/"
source "${path_bash}_private.sh"
source "${path_bash}config.sh"
source "${path_bash}utility.sh"
source "${path_bash}workflow.sh"
source "${path_bash}net.sh"
source "${path_bash}makeHTM.sh"

#
#
#
# Divider - Commands
#
#
#

cd ~/root
```

Comment: I'd suggest a file with only export statements for all the environment variables you are using, that way only this "config" file will need to change between environments

Answer (score 2):

Skip the `export` unless you really need it (that is, unless you need that variable to propagate to unrelated (=execed) processes that you execute).

If you do `export`, it's usually a good idea to capitalize the variable     (`export VAR=val`) to make it apparent that it will spread to executed binaries.

When you refer to a shell variable, you usually want to double quote it (`"$var"`) unless you need glob expansion and whitespace-splitting (splitting on `$IFS` characters, to be exact) done on that variable expansion.

Comment: I use mutliple files, does this effect anyting?  That is I have my variables in one file and I use the variables in another file. ( .sh files ).  Is this O.K>

Comment: If you source the files (`.` or `source`), then you don't need those `export`s.

Comment: I do use export, if I don't need export how do I declare the variable than?

Comment: you don't use the export builtin. Just: `var=val`

Comment: What is this `(=execed)` referring to ?

Comment: fork + exec is how Unixes create processes from executable files. fork creates a new process that continues the parent's process image; exec replaces the current process image with a process image loaded from a binary file. When you create a subshell with parentheses, it's a new process, but it continues with it's parent process image, which means it gets a copy of everything (including variables). When, however you run something ( a fork followed by an exec) the old process image is gone and only exported variables are passed across the exec call.

Answer (score -1):

sparrow automation framework gives you an opportunity to configure bash [scripts](https://sparrowhub.org) in many ways :

- passing command line named parameters
- configuration files in yaml format
- configuration files in json format
- configuration files in config::general format

Of course you need to pack your bash scripts into sparrow plugins first to get this behavior , but this is not a big deal . Follow https://github.com/melezhik/sparrow#configuring-tasks for details .

PS. disclosure - I am the sparrow tool author .